# how to fix translation error message in knp paginator symfony 3

Tags: symfony

i installed knp paginator bundle in symfony project and i got this warning appears to me
[image: error message]
[image: error output]
i have this error message after installing this bundle
is it due to this bundle or i have mess with something that cause this message

Comment: Are you using the latest KnpPaginationBundle? I find a new commit 22 days ago which includes translation for your locale (fr). Check your `/path/to/project/vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/Resources/translations` whether you see `KnpPaginatorBundle.fr.xliff` file there.

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/tree/master/Resources/translations

Comment: i have nstalled this bundle yesterday and i didnt find this file in my vendor so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution for this problem i opened the view of my pagination /path/to/project/vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/Resourc‌​es/views/pagination and i changed the english message with french and it works fine

```
 {% if pageCount > 1 %}
<ul class="pagination">
    {% if previous is defined %}
             <li class="arrow">
                 <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): previous})) }}">&laquo; {{ 'Précédant' }}</a>
             </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="arrow unavailable">
            <a>
                &laquo; {{ 'Précédant' }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if startPage > 1 %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): 1})) }}">1</a>
        </li>
        {% if startPage == 3 %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): 2})) }}">2</a>
            </li>
        {% elseif startPage != 2 %}
            <li class="unavailable">
                <a>&hellip;</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    {% for page in pagesInRange %}
        {% if page != current %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">
                    {{ page }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="current">
                <a>{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    {% if pageCount > endPage %}
        {% if pageCount > (endPage + 1) %}
            {% if pageCount > (endPage + 2) %}
                <li class="unavailable">
                    <a>&hellip;</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): (pageCount - 1)})) }}">
                        {{ pageCount -1 }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): pageCount})) }}">{{ pageCount }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if next is defined %}
        <li class="arrow">
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): next})) }}">
                {{ 'Suivant'}} &nbsp;&raquo;
            </a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="arrow unavailable">
            <a>
                {{ 'Suivant'}} &nbsp;&raquo;
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Symfony 4.x add the following to framework.yaml under config/packages:

translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }